# High DEX/STR scaling weapons?

Tags: dark-souls-3

Looking to do a quality build in DS3. Currently running with a sharp uchi. Which weapons in DS3 have high Dex/Str scaling, and are therefore good to use for a quality build?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check out the [damage calculator](http://trogg.net/DS3Calc/).

For example, at 12str+99dex maxed weapons:

Uchi has 400 AR.
Great scythe has 395 AR.
Carthus curved sword has 405 AR.
Farron greatsword has 480 AR.
Astora greatsword has 477 AR.
Lothric knight greatsword has 443 AR + 174 lightning.

Unfortunately it doesn't take into account infusions, which quite unpredictable. But you can try to infuse (a box at the middle left) and get aproximate AR values.

Comment: Also take a look at the Refined Gem infusion, for further improving Str/Dex scaling.

Comment: @klm123 your link doesn't work - for me it brings up a news site.